# JavaScript to change backgroundColor of grid cell on Click

Tags: javascript

I have basic HTML as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Art Maker!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monoton">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Pixel Art</h1>

    <h2>Choose Grid Size</h2>
    <form id="sizePicker">
        Grid Height:
        <input type="number" id="inputHeight" name="height" min="1" value="1">
        Grid Width:
        <input type="number" id="inputWidth" name="width" min="1" value="1">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <h2>Pick A Color</h2>
    <input type="color" id="colorPicker">

    <h2>Design Canvas</h2>
    <table id="pixelCanvas"></table>

    <script src="designs.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript below are used to:

1. obtain user input: height & width
2. draw grid based on height & width
3. obtain HTML color picker
4. fill a cell with background color based on step (3) when user click on the cell

I'm stuck at step (4). I created a function respondToClick(event) and attach it to tblRow with eventListener. It should fill the cell with background color when "click"; but it doesn't. Please advise where goes wrong.

// obtain grid size value; height & width

```
let height = document.getElementById('inputHeight').value;

let width = document.getElementById('inputWidth').value;

const gridHeight = document.getElementById('inputHeight');

gridHeight.addEventListener("input", function() {
  height = document.getElementById('inputHeight').value;
})

const gridWidth = document.getElementById('inputWidth');

gridWidth.addEventListener("input", function() {
  width = document.getElementById('inputWidth').value;
})
```

/ function to create canvas

```
const table = document.getElementById('pixelCanvas');

function createCanvas(event) {
  
  for (let h = 1; h <= height; h++) {
    const row = document.createElement('tr');
    
    for (let w = 1; w <= width; w++) {
      const cell = document.createElement('td');
      
      cell.style.cssText = "height: 15px; width: 15px";
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    
    table.appendChild(row);
  }  
}

const form = document.querySelector('form');
```

// bind createCanvas() to "submit"

```
form.addEventListener('submit', createCanvas);
```

// event listener to update color

```
let color = document.getElementById('colorPicker').value;

document.getElementById('colorPicker').onchange = function() {
  color = this.value;
}
```

// function activated when user click on  only

```
function respondToClick(event) {
  if (event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'td') {
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = color;
  }
}

const tblRow = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

tblRow.forEach(row => function() {
  row.addEventListener("click", respondToClick);
});
```

Comment: do you get any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following are the problems in your code:

- `document.getElementsByTagName(...)` returns a [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) on which you can't call `.forEach()` method. Instead use `document.querySelectorAll(...)` which returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) which has a method named `.forEach()`.

  ```
  const tblRow = document.querySelectorAll('tr');
  ```
- You need to prevent the default behaviour of the `submit` event using [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

  ```
  function createCanvas(event) {
     event.preventDefault();    
     ...
  }
  ```
- Since you had called `.forEach()` method on the [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) returned by `document.getElementsByTagName('tr')`, there was an error and no event listener was added on any of the `tr` element.

  Instead of adding `click` event listener on each `tr` element, you can take advantage of `Event Bubbling` and just add the event listener on the `table` element.

  ```
  table.addEventListener("click", respondToClick);
  ```

Following code snippet shows the fixed code example:

```js
let height = document.getElementById('inputHeight').value;
let width = document.getElementById('inputWidth').value;
const gridHeight = document.getElementById('inputHeight');
const gridWidth = document.getElementById('inputWidth');
const table = document.getElementById('pixelCanvas');
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const colorPicker = document.getElementById('colorPicker');
let color = colorPicker.value;

gridHeight.addEventListener("input", function() {
  height = document.getElementById('inputHeight').value;
})

gridWidth.addEventListener("input", function() {
  width = document.getElementById('inputWidth').value;
})

function createCanvas(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  for (let h = 1; h <= height; h++) {
    const row = document.createElement('tr');

    for (let w = 1; w <= width; w++) {
      const cell = document.createElement('td');
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }

    table.appendChild(row);
  }
}

form.addEventListener('submit', createCanvas);

colorPicker.addEventListener('change', function() {
  color = this.value;
});

function respondToClick(event) {
  if (event.target.matches('td')) {
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = color;
  }
}

table.addEventListener("click", respondToClick);
```

```css
table,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  ;
}

td {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Pixel Art</h1>

<h2>Choose Grid Size</h2>
<form id="sizePicker">
  Grid Height:
  <input type="number" id="inputHeight" name="height" min="1" value="1" /> Grid Width:
  <input type="number" id="inputWidth" name="width" min="1" value="1" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

<h2>Pick A Color</h2>
<input type="color" id="colorPicker" />

<h2>Design Canvas</h2>
<table id="pixelCanvas"></table>
```

---

**Side Note:** Inside the `responseToClick()` event handler, you have the following line of code:

```
cell.style.cssText = "height: 15px; width: 15px";
```

Although this works, it is better to define these styles in the CSS. I have done the same in the above code snippet.

Another point that should be noted is that after fixing the code as shown in the above code snippet, you might want to remove the previously created table contents before creating a new one. If this is what you want to do, then you can do this by setting the `.innerHTML` of the `table` element to an empty string inside the `createCanvas()` event handler.

Comment: thanks for your advice. Actually I know that using CSS to style the table, rows and cells are easier. I am deliberately want to practise JavasScripts, hence I try to do everything with JavasScripts. Just curious about your point...add table.innerHTML = "" in respondToClick event handler. How will clear table content? In fact, this is the next step. I put table.innerHTML = "" in createCanvas, right after event.preventDefault(). It does clear the table content. I also would like to know, after the table is created and click on the cell, how can I use JS to find out background color?

Comment: Actually, `table.innerHTML = ''` should be inside the `createCanvas()` function. That was a mistake in my answer which is fixed now. As far as your second question is concerned, i don't understand what you are asking when you say _how can I use JS to find out background color?_. Background color of what?

Comment: alright, thanks for clarify that. Ok, let me be more specific. After I click on the cell, the cell will be assigned a background color. In this case, how can I use JavaScript to find out whether any cell within the table has specific background color? For example, I click on one cell in the table, the cell is filled with BLUE color. How do I list the background color of that cell? or retrieve the table/row and list the background color?

Comment: You can select all the `td` elements in the `table`, then iterate over the collection and use [`Window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to get the styles on any `td` element.

Answer (score 2):

a couple of issues

- you should bind the click handler after creating the `rows` since you bind to the `tr`. Or better yet, since you already delegate the event, use the table element to bind the handler, since it is there from the beginning.
- you need to stop the form from actually submitting (*causes a reload of the page*)
- you need to clear the canvas when creating a new one

```js
// obtain grid size value; height & width

const gridHeight = document.getElementById('inputHeight');
const gridWidth = document.getElementById('inputWidth');

let height = gridHeight.value;
let width = gridWidth.value;

gridHeight.addEventListener("input", function() {
  height = document.getElementById('inputHeight').value;
})

gridWidth.addEventListener("input", function() {
  width = document.getElementById('inputWidth').value;
})

const table = document.getElementById('pixelCanvas');

function createCanvas(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  table.innerHTML = '';
  for (let h = 1; h <= height; h++) {
    const row = document.createElement('tr');

    for (let w = 1; w <= width; w++) {
      const cell = document.createElement('td');
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    table.appendChild(row);
  }
}

const form = document.querySelector('form');

// bind createCanvas() to "submit"
form.addEventListener('submit', createCanvas);

// event listener to update color
const picker = document.getElementById('colorPicker')
let color = picker.value;

picker.onchange = function() {
  color = this.value;
}

// function activated when user click on only

function respondToClick(event) {
  if (event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'td') {
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = color;
  }
}

table.addEventListener("click", respondToClick);
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
 }
 
 td{
 width:15px;
 height:15px;
 overflow:hidden;
 }
```

```html
<h1>Pixel Art</h1>

<h2>Choose Grid Size</h2>
<form id="sizePicker">
  Grid Height:
  <input type="number" id="inputHeight" name="height" min="1" value="1"> Grid Width:
  <input type="number" id="inputWidth" name="width" min="1" value="1">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<h2>Pick A Color</h2>
<input type="color" id="colorPicker">

<h2>Design Canvas</h2>
<table id="pixelCanvas" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"></table>
```

Comment: Another Issue that you missed it that you should absolutely use `label` for your input fields. So you know where to enter which value.

Comment: @cloned, yes that is good practice but is not related with the non-working code :)